# Oracle 17 driver is missing and Cannot access to MS SQL server in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mssql

i have a 16.04 version Ubuntu. I recently installed MSSQL server in the system. The version is SQL express 2019. Everything was ok during the installation . I followed the instructions in this link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/quickstart-install-connect-ubuntu?view=sql-server-ver15

I Have 4gb of Memory and space in HD (12 gb)
in the opt folder i see the MSSQL folder and MSSQL-TOOLS folder where i have the tool mssql-scmd

When i check the status seems ok:

```
 mssql-server.service - Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mssql-server.service; enabled; vendor pre
   Active: active (running) since Sun 2020-10-11 20:23:32 BST; 1h 39min ago
     Docs: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux
 Main PID: 998 (sqlservr)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mssql-server.service
           ├─ 998 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
           └─2485 /opt/mssql/bin/sqlservr
```

i try to access as per instructions with this command line

```
sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P '<YourPassword>'
```

(i set my password and click return)

Unfortunately in return i got:

Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'SA'..

If this is the problem any idea how to solve it?
not sure if i can find that driver easily?

Thanks in advance
Paolo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sorry to have posted the question. I am still not great with Linux. the system simply was saying that i was entering the wrong password. i changed it using the command:

```
/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-sa-password
```

I followed the guidelines contained in this [URL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/reset-sa-password-on-sql-server-on-linux)